# Cypher: Query to select two nodes connected by two instances of the same relation with different attributes?

Tags: neo4j, relationship, cypher

I have some node `n8` connected to another node `n9` by two instances of one and the same relation. These instances differ only by relation attribute `tag`. First relation instance have `tag = foo` and second instance has `tag = bar` (see code below).

What query will select these two nodes from all other nodes and relations? In other words: how to query two nodes connected **by two instances** of the **same relation** with **different attributes**?

```
create (n8 { id:'n8' })
create (n9 {id:'n9' })

MATCH (x),(y)
WHERE x.id = 'n8' AND y.id = 'n9'
CREATE (x)-[r:rl {tag:'foo'}]->(y)
RETURN r

MATCH (x),(y)
WHERE x.id = 'n8' AND y.id = 'n9'
CREATE (x)-[r:rl {tag:'bar'}]->(y)
RETURN r
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.   Use two `MATCH` clauses, paired with a `WHERE` clause that permits the relationship's `tag` to be any value in a list of possibilities:

```
MATCH (n8)-[firstRel:r1]->(n9),
      n8-[secondRel:r1]->n9
WHERE firstRel.tag in ['foo', 'bar'] AND
      secondRel.tag in ['foo', 'bar'] AND
      firstRel <> secondRel AND
      firstRel.tag <> secondRel.tag
return firstRel, secondRel
```

Comment: Thanks, yet as I described above I have `firstRel == secondRel`. Also, how this query will look like for any two arbitrary nodes, when you don't know their names and attributes?

Comment: If firstRel.tag="foo" and secondRel.tag="bar", then firstRel==secondRel cannot be true.   This query binds to ANY node with the attribute id='n8' and id='n9'.   So it won't look for any two arbitrary nodes, just ones with those IDs,  like you specified.

Comment: I have just one relation of type `rel` with a `tag` attribute which can take different values.  So I need to find nodes for which the following holds: `rel.tag ='foo' AND rel.tag = 'bar' ---nodes that have two instances of one and the same relation. I need this query to work for any arbitrary nodes withouts apripory knowledege of nodes attributes.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Now it works for any two nodes (not just ones with certain IDs) and requires that the tags be different.  Since there are two matched, and both have to have tag=foo or bar, and their tags have to be different, this guarantees two distinct relationships, one labeled foo the other bar.